# Typescript joining key names/ string types

Tags: javascript, string, typescript, types

Is there any way in typescript to dynamically join keys names / dynamically join string types? what i mean by that is :

```js
type JoinString<A extends string, B extends string> = /*some magic*/

const example = {
foo: "b",
bar: "c"
}

type GetAnotherKeys<T> = {
 JoinString<[TKey in keyof T], "_">: T[Tkey]
}

type Result = GetAnotherKeys<typeof example>;
/*
Result ={
foo_:string
bar_:string
}

*/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example:

```js
type AddPrefix<T extends string>=`${T}_`

type Keys={
   name:string;
   surname:string;
}

type MapPrefix<T>={
   [P in keyof T as AddPrefix<string & P>]:T[P]
}

type Result = MapPrefix<Keys>
```

More information you can find [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1/)

Comment: thank you kind gentelmen it is real luck that that update was week ago

Comment: @MaciejDot You are welcome. You can accept this answer, this will help other people